# check if multiple items inArray

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check if multiple items are contained within an array using jquery's inArray function?

```
if ($.inArray('foo' && 'bar', array) == -1) {
    // Neither foo or bar in array
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [**`jQuery.inArray`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), you can *(quoting)* :

> Search for a specified value within an
>   array and return its index (or -1 if
>   not found).

Looking at that documentation page, it doesn't seem you can pass more than one value to that function.

So, why not call that function twice : one time for `'foo'`, and one time for `'bar'` :

```
if ($.inArray('foo', array) == -1 && $.inArray('bar', array) == -1) {
    // Neither foo or bar in array
}
```

Comment: Just thought there might be a tidier way if say I want to pass 20 items to check.

Comment: If you have several items, you could put those in an array -- and, then, loop over that array of items, calling `jQuery.inArray` for each item.

Comment: Yep that's probably the best way of going about it!

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr= ['foo','bar'];
var length = arr.length;
for ( var i = 0 ;  i < length; i++ ) {
  if(jQuery.inArray(arr[i],array) > -1) {
   // do whatever you want.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
if (array.join(",").match(/foo|bar/gi).length == 2){
   //
}
```

or

```
var find = ["foo","bar"], exp = new RegExp(find.join("|"), "gi");
if (array.join(",").match(exp).length == find.length){
    //
}
```