# Match where text equals a passed value Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put a little script together that takes the value i have passed through and matches it aqgainst those that are on my page.. For example I am looking for all the instances of the word "Specsavers" on my page.

So in this example varName would be specsavers and each td.col-2 would contain a business name, maybe 3 of them are specsavers,  i need match these and do a count on how many instances of 'specsavers' there are

```
Selenium.prototype.doStoreTextOccurrence = function (locator, varName) {
    // Find where element is located (so parent div for example)
    var locator = this.page().findElement(locator);

    jQuery(locator).find('td.col-2').each(function (index, elem) {
        // though about using this below but cant work out how to 
        // pass through variables
        company = jQuery(elem).text(); 
        results = $("div:contains(varName)");
    });
}
```

Im a bit stuck at this point

thanks

Comment: if you use inArray? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/  Store your values in a local array and then use inArray to search the index. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579742/check-if-multiple-items-inarray

Comment: FYI, your code had several syntax errors. I've fixed them above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple jQuery selector:

```
var count = $('td.col-2:contains(' + varName + ')').length;
```

Comment: so no need to grab the text of each td.col-2 first? and out of interest how would i use the var 'company' in the contains script ?

Comment: Nope, the contains method will look at that.